# Using text in header of document as link to spreadsheet in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm trying to link a spreadsheet to a document. I've put the spreadsheet's id in the header of the document - (getChild(3) because I'm using 'different first page header'). In the log I get the right id value, but the script return "An unexpected error" for openById...

```
function spreadSheet(){
  var docFile = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var header = docFile.getHeader();
  var id = header.getParent().getChild(3).asHeaderSection().getText();
  //var id = header.getParent().getChild(3).asText().getText()
  //var id = '1cYX1uXHQdB0ee67YWLanB_ESTgGkG9NRJIQ34arIH2c'


  Logger.log(id)

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var hej = s.getRange('A1').getValue();
```

I've tried some different stuff as you can see in the code. When replacing the id with the text string in the last example it works as supposed. But I wan't the id to be defines in the document and not in the code.

[Link to the document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oh7u2kP96xlW8bdm-CmdcfRJz_gEX8UjxEE1WrNl97I/edit?usp=sharing)
[Link to simpel template spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cYX1uXHQdB0ee67YWLanB_ESTgGkG9NRJIQ34arIH2c/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the id will be the longest word in the header text so I'd guess that this will work.

```
function getSSIDFromHeader(){
  var docFile = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var header = docFile.getHeader();
  var text=header.getText().split(/(\n| |\r)/);//splitting on cr linefeed or space
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(text.reduce(function(a,s,i){if(s.length>a.max.length){a.max=s;}return a;},{max:''}).max),"Test");
}
```

I tested this on a document header of mine and it works. I suspect that it might on yours because I guess that it would  be the longest string in the header when split by either \r or \n or space

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. Well my problem isn't to extract the id. For that your code works well. But the last part of my code will neither work with your id finder code or mine.   
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var s = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
var hej = s.getRange('A1').getValue(); I've updated my post above with links to the documents and a picture of my document.

Comment: I've now tested a little further and it seems that the problem is related to the fact that I'm having "a different first page header".

Comment: If your getting the correct id then it should work.  I would be single stepping through the code and carefully insuring that what I get is what I expect.  If you don't know how to use the debugger then this is the day to begin that process.

Comment: I get the right id, but the script comes with an error (in Danish) something like (Exception: Der opstod en uventet fejl, da metoden eller ejendommen openById for objektet SpreadsheetApp skulle hentes. ) There is an unexpected error when the method openById getting the object SpreadsheetApp. When removing the "Different first page" from the document the code works.

Comment: So it sound like it has nothing to do with the openById().  You are not getting the right id. Perhaps it has white space in it that you are not seeing.

Comment: Again I think you're on your own.  It's debugger time.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was a line shift making the trouble.